# Custom formatting of xticks in Ploty.js and Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plotly, plotly.js

I'm trying to apply custom formatting for `xticks` and `yticks` in `Plotly.js` charts (using Vue wrapper for that library).

I tried using the standard d3 style formatting but was not able to apply the format I'm trying to achieve. I used:

```
xaxis: {
          tickformat: ",.2f",
        },
```

So that `200000` is formatted as `200,000.00` but my desired format is to have space as thousands separator so that `200000` becomes `200 000.00`. I can't find how that works in d3 style formatting. Is there a straightforward way to apply the formatting to the values displayed on the plot?

Here is my example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-barchart-pw78w?file=/src/layout.vue

Comment: Have you read this? https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md#locale_format

Comment: Yep, as I mentioned in the question, I could not find this formatting pattern in d3.

Comment: Did you try to change locale in vue? Probably something like `en-ZA` might work

Comment: @fdermishin Not sure how would that work with the vue-plotly. library

Comment: Because thousands separator is `' '` instead of `','` in that locale. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Examples_of_use

Comment: I see, but the problem is that I cant find a way to change local in plotly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to define your thousands separator like below:

```
options: {
        responsive: true,
        locale: "en",
        locales: {
          en: {
            format: { thousands: " " },
          },
        },
```

[Corrected code](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-barchart-forked-hwsnc?file=/src/layout.vue)
[Referecnce](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/plot_api/plot_config.js)